# What is the cost of swapping two std::array<T, 100> objects?

Tags: c++, arrays

I imagine the internals of a `std::vector` to be a **pair of pointers** pointing to the beginning and the end of the occupied memory and an **integer** specifying the length of the memory array that belongs to the vector. Therefore swapping two vectors of the same size should cost only **3** swaps of built in types.

However I almost never use `std::array` and therefore I do not know how to imagine its internals. Intuitively, since the compiler already knows the size of the array there is no need to store the end of the array or the size of preallocated memory so its internals should be just 1 pointer. Therefore the cost should be **just 1 built in type swap**.

Instead the documentation says that the cost is [linear in the number of elements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/swap2). Why is this so?

Comment: `std::array` is a template around a raw array. So yeah swapping is O(N) and unless you `new` it, it'll be on the stack so swap will involve memcpy which would be O(N).

Comment: @Borgleader What if you do `new std::array<int, 100>`? ;-)

Comment: @delnan Then your variable is a pointer to an array... :P I realize I should have said raw array. Let me fix that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because an array is not a pointer. It's literally n inline values. A `std::array` doesn't allocate space elsewhere for N objects, it *is* the space for N objects, as if it has members `value1, value2, value3, ...` only with a guarantee of no padding (which allows indexing). You're thinking of the as-of-yet-hypothetical `std::dynarray`. These two objects:

```
std::array<T, 100> a;
std::dynarray<T> b;
```

looks like this in memory:

```
a: +-+-+-+-+-+
   |T|T|T|...|
   +-+-+-+-+-+

b: ptr ----------> +-+-+-+-+-+
                   |T|T|T|...|
                   +-+-+-+-+-+
```

Comment: So the compiler remembers the address of every single of those n values?

Comment: @MartinDrozdik It usually just reasons about the n values as a whole, because the address of the `i`th element is trivial to find with pointer arithmetic (and not of interest to the *compiler* anyway).

Comment: and is there something that forbids the compiler to swap the two structures in constant time? Is there some advantage that would be lost if `std::array` were implemented using just a pointer?

Comment: So if I want to have an array, whose length I know at compile time and I need to swap two arrays many times (e.g. when doing a quicksort) I should explicitly use pointers to `std::array`. Is that true?

Comment: @MartinDrozdik It may or may not be the best approach (raw pointers are definitely discouraged) but yes, that or similar indirection is necessary to make the swap cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

> Therefore the cost should be just 1 built in type swap. Instead the documentation says that the cost is linear in the number of elements. Why is this so?

Because the complexity for a C-style array [is linear](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) and `std::array` is just a *wrapper* to a C-style array. Intuitively this is obvious: you have to swap every element of the array with each other.

---

> I imagine the internals of a std::vector to be a pair of pointers pointing to the beginning and the end of the occupied memory and an integer specifying the length of the memory array that belongs to the vector.

Well, maybe. Some implementations just store a pointer to a dynamically allocated array, an `std::size_t` member and an integral value for the *capacity* (there's no need to store the pointer to the end of the array as it can be easily retrieved via `begin + size`), with the cost of pointer arithmetics when calling `push_back` or `end`. Other implementations store two pointers to the begin and end (like you said) with the cost of `end - begin` when calling `size`.

> Intuitively, since the compiler already knows the size of the array there is no need to store the end of the array or the size of preallocated memory so its internals should be just 1 pointer.

No, the `std::array` class is just "an aggregate type with the same semantics as a struct holding a C-style array `T[N]` as its only non-static data member".

Comment: @Jeffrey Thank you! I guess I need to understand C style arrays first.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik, you really don't. Just understand that all elements of the `std::array` are allocated automatically (in what most people call "the stack"). There are no pointers involved, most of the time.

Comment: I doubt the first paragraph is true (I've heard that the usual implementations store a start and end pointer instead of a start pointer and a length integer, to avoid pointer arithmetic for `push_back`, `end`, and other common methods), but more importantly it doesn't matter. Tthe various representations are isomorphic and none has a huge advantage and the number of primitives to store/swap is the same, and that's all that matters for this question.